# Is there a rule for deciding dictionary size for sentiment analysis with massive datasets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I will be performing sentiment analysis on fiction. I'll be working with around 300 books of 350 pages. Can I limit the dictionary size by ignoring less frequent words? If so, what is the rule for defining the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any such "rule". If you plan to use deep learning I think the only limiting factor is how many words you can afford to train with due to memory/time constraints. But sill you can obtain close to best accuracy by limiting to a subset of most common words. I think around 50000 words would be a reasonable start if you are dealing with one language. From there you can expand vocabulary size if you need better performance.